# Group by one column and return several columns on multiple conditions - T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables which I can generate with SELECT statements (joining multiple tables) as follows:

Table 1:

| ID | Site | type | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dallas | 2 | 01-01-2021 |
| 2 | Denver | 1 | 02-01-2021 |
| 3 | Chicago | 1 | 03-01-2021 |
| 4 | Chicago | 2 | 29-11-2020 |
| 5 | Denver | 1 | 28-02-2020 |
| 6 | Toronto | 2 | 11-05-2019 |

Table 2:

| ID | Site | collected | deposited |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Denver | NULL | 29-01-2021 |
| 2 | Denver | 01-04-2021 | 29-01-2021 |
| 3 | Chicago | NULL | 19-01-2020 |
| 4 | Dallas | NULL | 29-01-2019 |
| 5 | Winnipeg | 13-02-2021 | 17-01-2021 |
| 6 | Toronto | 14-02-2020 | 29-01-2020 |

I would like the result to be grouped by Site, having on each column the COUNT of type=1 , type=2, deposited and collected, all of the 4 columns between a selected time interval. Example: (interval between 01-06-2020 and 01-06-2021:

| Site | type1 | type2 | deposited | collected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dallas | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Denver | 1 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| Chicago | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Toronto | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Winnipeg | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: Are there only ever two types?

Comment: Why does Toronto have two `0`s?

Comment: Because the package was deposited and collected at the beginning of 2020, outside the interval selected

Comment: Martin, there are multiple types in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `union all` and aggregation?

```
select site,
       sum(case when type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as type_1,
       sum(case when type = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as type_2,
       sum(deposited) as deposited, sum(collected) as collected
from ((select site, type, 0 as deposited, 0 as collected
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select site, null, 
              (case when deposited is not null then 1 else 0 end),
              (case when collected is not null then 1 else 0 end)
       from table2
      )
     ) t12
group by site;
```

Comment: I am struggling to apply this to my context. What does t12 stand for?

Comment: Also, where would I add the time constraints? In each of the select statements in the FROM clause or just once, right before GROUP BY?

Comment: I think I have managed to apply this, but I am getting an error stating "operand data type datetime is invalid for sum operator". I believe it does not want to sum dates of deposited and collected. I have tried with a COUNT, but it also returned an error stating "cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery"

Comment: @Tucker . . . It is a table alias, which is needed for a subquery in the `FROM` clause.  You can add the time constraints to the subqueries.  And I fixed the last problem.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, that solved it. One last question. Is it possible to have a flag when the count of type2 is less than 80% of type1 and when the collected is less than 80% of the deposited?

Comment: @Tucker . . . Probably.  You would just use a `case` expression in the outer query.  If you need help, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

- Combine your tables 1 and 2 with a join on Site
- Use `COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 1 then 1 END) as type1` and a similar construct for type 2
- Use `COUNT(CASE WHEN somedate BETWEEN '2020-06-01' and '2021-06-01' then 1 END) as ...` for your dates